# Rails associations simple questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a demo app im making which will allow users to select a show and then add that show to their account. Multiple users can have the same show however.

The way i have it set up at the moment is as follows:

```
###models/user.rb####
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shows, through: :user_shows

###models/show.rb####
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_shows
  has_many :users, through: :user_shows

###models/user_show.rb####
class UserShow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :show
```

So what would need to add so that when a user hits  a button "add" (currently it only links to an #) then that will add that show to their account?

This is my current add button in the views:

```
<% @shows.each do |show| %>
          <div class="well well-sm welly">
            <p><%= link_to show.title, show.url, class: "btn btn-primary", target: "blank" %>  
                <%= link_to "Add Show", users_add_show_path, class: "btn btn-danger addbt" %>
            </p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

I also updated my controller as per Rich's help.

**UPDATE**
Here are my other files
routes.rb

```
 ShowReminder::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :shows
  resources :users do
   collection do
       post :add_show #-> should create /users/add_show, considering you have current_user
   end
end
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'features' => 'pages#features'
  get 'my_shows' => 'pages#my_shows'
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController



    def add_show
        show = Show.find params[:id]
        current_user.shows << show
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def show
    end

end
```

views/shows/index.html.erb (only part of it)

```
<div>
        <% @shows.each do |show| %>
          <div class="well well-sm welly">
            <p><%= link_to show.title, show.url, class: "btn btn-primary", target: "blank" %>  
                <%= link_to "Add Show", add_show_users(show.id), class: "btn btn-danger addbt" %>
            </p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= will_paginate @shows, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, :inner_window => 1, :outer_window => 0, class: "paginates" %>
```

Error messages:

Error 1: Without

```
def show
end
```

in my Userscontroller

```
The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController
```

Error2: With it in my controller:

```
Missing template users/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/Harrison/Documents/Projects/show_reminder/app/views" * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Multiple users can have the same show

You'll be best looking at [`many-to-many` relationships](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in Rails. This is where you use a `join model`, or similar, to associate multiple items to multiple objects. There are two types of `m-t-m` relationship:

- [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)
- [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

---

**Code**

You'll be best doing something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
has_many :user_shows
has_many :shows, through: :user_shows

#app/models/user_show.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :show

#app/models/show.rb
has_many :user_shows
has_many :users, through: :user_shows
```

This is classic `has_many :through`:

[image]

This will allow you to call `@user.shows` or `@show.users`

---

**Button**

Adding `shows` to a `User` is actually relatively simple

Using the `many-to-many` structure, your `shows` will be an [`ActiveRecord Collection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). As such, you'll have access to the `<<` method, which can be called like this:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def add_show
    show = Show.find params[:id]
    current_user.shows << show # -> only works with AR objects. current_user is AR object
end
```

This will allow you to do something like this:

```
#app/views/users/add_show.html.erb
<%= form_tag users_add_show_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :id, placeholder: "Show ID" %> #-> should be a select box - can refactor
    <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   collection do
       post :add_show #-> should create /users/add_show, considering you have current_user
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, this helped me understand it a lot more. I updated my question to include my current add button, but for some reason it isn't working, if you could take a look that would be a big help. Thaks

Comment: You have `users_add_show_path` but are not passing any `id`. You'd need `users_add_show_path(show.id)` or similar

Comment: hmm ive tried a few variations but just can't seem to get it to work. Also I thought because I was going through @show.each |show| that it would mean that it would take the show_id from that? Is this right?

Comment: You'd use `show.id` - have you updated your `routes`? When you mention it doesn't work - do you have any errors?

Comment: ahh ok. What/how would i need to update them (sorry for the noobish questions this is all very confusing for me). here is the error message:
`undefined method` `users_add_show_path' for #<#<Class:0x51e4d68>:0x4053918>`

Comment: Thanks for that. That solved that error (i had to change it to add_show_users_path(show.id) for the button) but now it seems to give me `The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController`. When i def this method in UsersController I get a template error and still cant seem to get past that. Ideas? Sorry for all the questions - you have been a big help

Comment: It's okay! The template error can be fixed by adding `redirect_to root_path` at the end of the `add_show` action

Comment: That still isn't working for some reason? BTW i should have mentioned when it was asking for the template it was asking for the show.html.erb template and not the add_show.html.erb one. I can't figure out though where exactly it is getting the action "show" from. I have changed all the variables names, yet that always stays the same with "show". I will update will all my files.

Comment: Hmmm - can you post the actual error on your question for us please?

Comment: Just added it all in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54099/discussion-between-harrylucas-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 0):

In User model define one more relation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_shows
```

In action where the add button will hit sending show_id in params `id`

```
current_user.user_shows.create(:show_id => params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just with that last bit im a little confused. How would I add it to this?
`<%= link_to "Add Show", '#' %>`
because if I replace the # with it i get an error